# Trying to get switch case logic correct in java

Tags: java, object, switch-statement

Hi I've been trying to get this system where based on the firepower's number it will determined the number of fired bullets.

So i created a switch statement that will allow it to take the previous bullet creation points and add on new ones as the fire power increases. The problem is I don't know how to account for numbers not used. I try using default but then I realized that since I put  it at the top it would go through the higher firepower bullet upgrades without reaching that number yet.

Is there a way to make it do certain ones as when a value has been choosen? (Keep in mind I do want to still be using the original bullet upgrades) The only other way I can think of it is nesting many different if or else statements. Would that be the way to

my code:

```
    switch(firePower){

    case 30:
        for(int i = -4; i <=4; i++){
            Bullet a = new Bullet((int)playerx,(int)playery+i,-i);
            bullet.add(a);
        }
    case 15:
        for(int i = -2; i <=2; i++){
            Bullet a = new Bullet((int)playerx,(int)playery+i,-i);
            bullet.add(a);
        }

    case 4:
        Bullet h = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-10, 0);
        Bullet i = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-12, 0);
        bullet.add(h);
        bullet.add(i);
    case 3:
        Bullet f = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-6, 0);
        Bullet g = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-8, 0);
        bullet.add(f);
        bullet.add(g);
    case 2:
        Bullet d = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery+4, 0);
        Bullet e = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-4, 0);
        bullet.add(d);
        bullet.add(e);
    case 1:
        Bullet b = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery+2, 0);
        Bullet c = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-2, 0);
        bullet.add(b);
        bullet.add(c);
    case 0:
        Bullet a = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery, 0);
        bullet.add(a);
        break;

    }
```

Comment: add `break;` statement in the end of each case

Comment: Adding a break statement would not work as I want to add on the previous bullet positions.

Comment: You actually don't need the final `break` statement.

Comment: But your desire to be able to have `case` selected for a range of values is not possible in standard Java (though I've heard rumors it's coming).  You either need to enumerate all 30 cases (which could be `case 30: case 29: case 28:...`) or else use `if/else` logic for the first two cases.

Comment: I forgot that I could just type the case 30: case 29: and so on without putting anything in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question what you can do with switch statement is this.

```
 case 15:
 case 14:
 case 13:
 case 12:
 case 11:
 case 10:
 case 9:
 case 8:
 case 7:
 case 6:
 case 5:
        for(int i = -2; i <=2; i++){
            Bullet a = new Bullet((int)playerx,(int)playery+i,-i);
            bullet.add(a);
        }

    case 4:
        Bullet h = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-10, 0);
        Bullet i = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-12, 0);
        bullet.add(h);
        bullet.add(i);
    case 3:
        Bullet f = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-6, 0);
        Bullet g = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-8, 0);
        bullet.add(f);
        bullet.add(g);
    case 2:
        Bullet d = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery+4, 0);
        Bullet e = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-4, 0);
        bullet.add(d);
        bullet.add(e);
    case 1:
        Bullet b = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery+2, 0);
        Bullet c = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery-2, 0);
        bullet.add(b);
        bullet.add(c);
    case 0:
        Bullet a = new Bullet((int)playerx, (int)playery, 0);
        bullet.add(a);
        break;

    }
```

Comment: Well like I said I want it to execute the rest (it's what I mean by "take the previous bullet creation points"). Also since there are going to be times when it's between 4 and 15 I still want it to do what is under 4 and bellow, but when it comes to 15 I want it to do what is 15 and bellow.

Comment: @mkjrfan i don't understand your question. if your case is 15 then it will executed all cases below 15

Comment: yes but what if it's between 4 and 15? Nothing will shoot if it's between those numbers

Comment: @mkjrfan and what code do you want to execute? the same as 15?

Comment: Basically I want to execute everything under the number. For example if it was firePower = 3 it would execute what is under 3,2,1. If firePower = 10; I would want it to execute what is under 4,3,2,1.

Comment: @mkjrfan as you note using this is not very `OOP` solution. May be it's better using `if else` in this case or a dessign pattern like a factory to delegate creation and put theh logic creation in factories!

Comment: It should be noted that, given the above, one could use `default` for the range 30-16.

Comment: @HotLicks that's a good point but i don't know if 30-16 are all valid entries

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `break;` after each `case` or else it will execute everything until it reaches a `break;`.

```
case n:
    /* some code */
    break;
```

On a side note, `break;` can also be used in loops when you want to forcefully exit a loop before its own condition to exit is met.

Also, as Josh M mentioned, there is a `default:` case option that can be used as it sounds, by default, if no `case:` switch evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I also think it is worth noting that the `default` case will execute if none of the other `case`s are true.

Comment: I did state that what I wanted was to add on so adding breaks would not really work unless I was to copy the same code over and over again.

Comment: With the default method, I already stated my problem on why it wont work if were to place it on top.